# Java Sound File Not Playing3

Tags: java, audio, javasound

hello i have this code to open sound wav file but it didnt work

```
  import java.io.IOException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
  import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
  import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
 import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
 import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
 import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
 import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
 import sun.applet.Main;


 public class Sound1 {


 public static Mixer mixer;
 public static Clip clip;
 public static void main(String[] args)          {              
    // TODO code application logic here
    Mixer.Info[] mixinfo =AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
     for(Mixer.Info info :mixinfo)
    {
        System.out.println(info.getName()+"...."+info.getDescription());
        mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixinfo[0]);

    }
        DataLine.Info datainfo =new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, null);

        try
        {
            clip =(Clip)mixer.getLine(datainfo);
        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException lue)
        {
            lue.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {
            URL soundurl = Main.class.getResource("1.wav");
            AudioInputStream audiostream =                                 `enter code here`AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundurl);
            clip.open(audiostream);

        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException lue)
        {
            lue.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        clip.start();

        do
        {
            try { Thread.sleep(50);}
            catch (InterruptedException ie){ ie.printStackTrace();}
        }while(clip.isActive());

          }

         }
```

i cant run the program there is error please i need help  i think the error here"URL soundurl = Main.class.getResource("1.wav");" althought i add th i.wav file to the project

Comment: Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: Is 1.wav in the same directory as "Main"? There is some odd stuff in your code, e.g., "  'enter code here... that would mess things up.

Answer (score 0):

Not all Mixers are available for audio output (Some are audio input only). In your code, you're always choosing the first mixer in the Mixer.Info[] array, which maybe doesn't support audio output. You can check this by calling

```
mixer.isLineSupported(datainfo);
```

If you are not really needing a mixer (you usally need it when playing multiple audio files that need to be synchronized) you can play a simple .wav file with

```
public void play(File file) throws LineUnavailableException{
  Clip clip=AudioSystem.getClip();
  clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file));
  clip.loop(1);
}
```

Further information:
[Accessing Audio System Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html)